# Ignore new line in a column when reading a csv

Tags: python, csv

I am having a problem processing a csv that I'm loading into an sql database.

The csv has several free text fields and there are some new line characters in the data. This is causing a line to be broken into two rows.

What I would like to do it to setup the code to basically replace new line character with a space when the line has less split character than expected. Because I know how many columns to expect. I really have no idea how I would do this. My current code is below.

```
batch = list()
with open(file, "r", errors='ignore') as f:
    for l in f.readlines()[1:]:
        # append the processed row to the batch list
        # processed row meaning we strip down the fields to remove redundant data
        # and add Nones if the length of the row is not up to the FIELDS_COUNT
        list_pre = l.split("#|#")
        batch.append([i.strip() for i in list_pre])
```

So the input looks like this:

```
col1#|#col2#|#col3#|#col4#|#col5


col1#|#col2#|#co


l3#|#col4#|#col5

col1#|#col2#|#col3#|#col4#|#col5

col1#|#col2#|#col3#|#col4#|#col5
```

expected output:

```
['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5']

['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5']

['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5']

['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5']
```

Comment: Please also provide a minimal sample input/expected-output: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: are you trying to avoid unnecessary line break?

Comment: essentially yes

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
for row in cursor2.fetchall():
    temp_list = []
    for item in row:
        if isinstance(item, str):
            item = item.strip()
        temp_list.append(item)
    row = tuple(temp_list)
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: This looks like it's fetching data from a database in storing it. I'm not sure how this is addressing my problem. Can you help me understand? I'm trying to process a csv.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this is how I addressed it, basically I said if the fields are less than the total columns append the next row. To be honest this doesn't work if there are multiple new lines in one row, so it may not work at some future point, but it works for now

```
file = 'fakecsv.txt'

batch = list()
list_pre0 = []
print(len(list_pre0))
with open(file, "r", errors='ignore') as f:
    for l in f.readlines()[1:]:

        list_pre = l.split("#|#")
        if len(list_pre) < 4:
            print(len(list_pre))
            if len(list_pre0) == 0:
                list_pre0 = list_pre
            else:
                replace_value = list_pre0[-1].replace('\n','') + list_pre[0]
                print('replace value equals: ' + replace_value)
                del list_pre0[-1]
                del list_pre[0]   
                list_pre0.append(replace_value)
                combined =  list_pre0 + list_pre
                batch.append([i.strip() for i in combined])
                list_pre0 = []
            continue
        print(len(list_pre))
        batch.append([i.strip() for i in list_pre])
   print(batch)
```